# Dynamic ajax data loading with Backbone/Marionette (for ex. infinite scroll)

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Can you suggest solutions for dynamic model loading with Backbone/Marionette like in case of infinite scroll?

My common code looks like:

```
Drivers = new AppList.DriverCollection
Drivers.url = $('#drivers-url').text()
Drivers.fetch()
```

Request goes to my django backend:

```
def ajax_get_drivers(request):
    drivers = Driver.objects.all()
    data = []
    for driver in drivers:
        data.append({
            'id': driver.pk,
            'name': driver.name,
            'phone': driver.phone
        })
    response = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

How to break it on parts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details for your question?

If you just want to make infinite scroll of loading models, I can show you a example. http://codeboard.org/#codes

You can find the loading model JS code in *js/views/code/CodeListView.js*, and the bind scroll event code in *js/bootstrap.js*, and php code in *src/CodeBoard/Route/CodeRoute.php* (On Github, you can review the source code).